# A problem on convergence of a given sequence of complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given the sequence of complex functions $f_{n}(z)=1/(1+az^n)$,$a\neq0$. I have to show that this sequence converges uniformly to 1 on every compact subset of $B_1(0)=\{z| z<1\}$ and that it converges uniformly to $0$ on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus B_r(0)$ for $r>1$.
Since i am not so well versed in analysis, i wanted to attack it with the definition of uniform convergence but it turned out to be ( for me at least very hard ).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the M-test.

Comment: the M-test is for series, on my understanding.
i do not have to show that the series converges, just that the sequence converges

Answer (score 0):

Any compact $K$ is within a positive distance from the boundary of the disk, $|z|\le r<1$ in $K$. In $K$, you have
$$
|\frac{1}{1+az^n}-1|=|a|\frac{|z|^n}{|1+az^n|}\le |a|\frac{r^n}{1-|a|r^n}\le 2|a|r^n
$$
if $n$ is large enough, such that $|a|r^n<1/2$ (where the triangle inequality has been used).  The limit in the RHS is zero, since $r<1$, and the bound is independent of $z\in K$, so we are done.
The proof is similar for compacts contained in the complement of the closed disk.

Comment: how do you get the last two inequalities ?

Comment: By the triangle inequality, $|1+az^n|\ge |1-|a||z|^n|$. If $|z|\le r$ and $n$ is such that $|a|r^n<1/2$, you have  $|a||z|^n\le |a|r^n<1/2$ and $1-|a||z|^n>1/2$. Finally, $1/|1+az^n|<1/(1/2)=2$ for such $z$ and $n$.

Comment: @Dan Anything yet unclear?

Comment: absolutely not 
Thanks again